# Easier way to get one of two variables to have one of two options randomly?

Tags: c#, random

I got two variables, `x` and `y`. One of these should have random int value from `0` to `721 - this.Width`. The other one has to be either value `0` or `721 - this.Width`. I've already managed to create this, but such a long code seems stupid for such a small thing. Might be that this is the only (or best) solution, but I'm asking to be sure, is there a shorter way?

Here's my code:

```
Random random = new Random();
int x, y;
if (random.Next(2) == 1)
{
    x = random.Next(721 - this.Width);
    if (random.Next(2) == 1)
    {
        y = 721 - this.Height;
    }
    else
    {
        y = 0;
    }
}
else
{
    y = random.Next(721 - this.Height);
    if (random.Next(2) == 1)
    {
        x = 721 - this.Width;
    }
    else
    {
        x = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree, just place it in a nicely named method and you can easily unit test and leverage it without worrying about its length; I think there are a few too many logic gates to simplify much beyond this without losing meaning. However, I'm wondering if your `y = 721 - this.Height;` and `x = 721 - this.Height;` lines are correct. Did you intend for _one_ of them to subtract `Width` instead?

Comment: @ChrisSinclair Good catch, fixed it :P But I guess I'll just have to deal with this then, looks awful in the code but who cares, it works ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it to take up fewer lines then you can do this:

```
Random random = new Random();
int x, y;
switch (random.Next(2))
{
    case 1:
        x = random.Next(721 - Width);
        y = random.Next(2) == 1 ? 721 - Height : 0;
        break;
    default:
        y = random.Next(721 - Height);
        x = random.Next(2) == 1 ? 721 - Width : 0;
        break;
}
```

Credit goes to Resharper.

Answer (score 2):

You could write it like this:

```
Random random = new Random();
int a = random.Next(2) * (721 - this.Width);
int b = random.Next(721 - this.Width);
int c = random.Next(2) * (721 - this.Height);
int d = random.Next(721 - this.Height);
int x, y;

Boolean t = (random.Next(2) == 1);
x = (t) ? a : b;
y = (t) ? d : c;
```

Note that this code is no better than yours if you find the longer version easier to understand. There is no *right* way to write code, and understandability is often more valuable than brevity.

Answer (score 1):

It's not too bad. I think the best you can do is move it to a nice helper utility to hide the complexity. Perhaps you can assign the various `random.Next(0, 1)` results to named booleans:

```
public class PositionCalculator
{
    private Random random = new Random();

    public Point CalculatePosition(int width, int height)
    {
        int x, y;

        bool favourWidth = RandomBoolean();
        bool useZeroForOther = RandomBoolean();

        int favouredValue = random.Next(721 - (favourWidth ? width : height));
        int otherValue = useZeroForOther ? 0 : (721 - (favourWidth ? height : width));

        if (favourWidth)
        {
            x = favouredValue;
            y = otherValue;
        }   
        else
        {
            x = otherValue;
            y = favouredValue;
        }

        return new Point() { X = x, Y = y };
    }

    private bool RandomBoolean()
    {
        return random.Next(2) == 1;
    }
}
```

At least this way, however you want to play around with the internal implementation it doesn't really matter to the rest of your application. I had this get the `Width` and `Height` passed in just to avoid requiring it to have a reference to the UI layer.

EDIT: Really, even with this, I still find the "logic" path hard to follow with the ternary operators. Feel free to use whatever ifs or method structure makes the most sense for you to maintain it and still understand it when you look at the algorithm again months/years from now.

Answer (score 0):

```
var max = 721 - this.Width;
var rand = new Random();
var r = rand.Next(max * 2);
var x = r % max;
var y = (r / max) * max;
if (rand.Next(2) == 1) {var t = x; x = y; y = t;}
```